# Removing elements of a specific type from vectors in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to figure out how to remove elements from a vector or list in clojure of a specific type. Say, I have a list that contains strings and integers. And I wanted to create a list with just the strings and another list with the numbers.

How would I go about that?

E.G. `[1 2 "Hello" 3 4 "Bye"]` would become `[1 2 3 4]` and `["Hello" "Bye"]`

Also how I might go about that same thing if I had lists inside a list or even a step deeper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way:

```
((juxt filter remove) string? [1 2 "Hello" 3 4 "Bye"])
;; [("Hello" "Bye") (1 2 3 4)]
```

Comment: That could work, but the only I could see like in the previous answer is if I needed to access each new list how I would go about it since it seems to return two or more lists. Is there a way to just return the list of strings or ints? Also, could you maybe explain to me what juxt does? Thanks

Comment: well, if you want just one type then do either `(filter string? your-list)` or `(remove string? your-list)` in this case (just an example). Look at the documentation for `juxt`, it juxtaposes the results of both operations (creates a list with both lists).

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out, got my solution to work. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You could use `group-by`:

```
(group-by type [1 2 "hello" 3 4 "Bye"]) 
;; returns {java.lang.Long [1 2 3 4], java.lang.String ["hello" "Bye"]}
```

Comment: Yeah, that could work. The only issue would be accessing both of those lists to do things with. Say that it was part of a bigger function and I wanted to add up all the numbers or something. How would I go about that?

Comment: using `type` is generally a bad idea here. try this for example: `(group-by type [1 2 1.0 1/2 "hello" "world"])`. The result is probably not what you want

Comment: JCD you could access via the returned map and the type you want as a key. @leetwinski, he asked for strings and integers specifically, but I sure agree with your point. In a general case, I would use something like Diego's answer.